# Is product opportunity frontier the same as PPF?

Tags: microeconomics

In CFA level 1 reading 14, they have this term called Production Opportunity frontier and it is defined as

*Curve describing the maximum number of units of one good a company can produce, for any given number of the other good that it chooses to manufacture.*

The graph is a straight line

[image]

Is it the same thing as what is commonly known Production Possibility Frontier with the curved line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The "curved line" clearly fits your definition as well. The PPF is curved if (but not only if) there are diminishing returns to inputs such as labor and capital. See also
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Production%E2%80%93possibility_frontier

Answer (score -2):

No they are not same. Production Possibility Frontier is the maximum amount of output that can be produced using different combination of inputs. However this opportunity frontier is the tradeoff between different outputs that a firm can produce. In order to increase production of one output it has to decrease production of another.

Comment: Actually this is called the Production Possibility Frontier.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Production%E2%80%93possibility_frontier What you describe is an isoquant. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isoquant

Comment: You are right. My bad!